# Exponent vectorization in Octave

Tags: vectorization, octave

I'm attempting to take a general array `A`, raise it to the (element-wise) power of each member of a vector `p`, and sum the result, preferably in a vector operation, such that the result is the same size as `A`. Ideally, arrays of any size/dimension for `A` should be allowed. For example, if

```
A = [0 1 ; 2 3]
p = [2 3]
```

I want the result `A.^p(1) + A.^p(2)`, which is `[0 2 ; 12 36]`, just more elegantly, and for any size of `A` and length of `p`, and avoiding a loop.

I came up with the following, which expands into the next higher dimension of `A`, then sums along that dimension:

`sum(repmat(A,[ones(1,ndims(A)) length(p)]) .^ repmat(reshape(p,[ones(1,ndims(A)) length(p)]),size(A)),ndims(A)+1)`

which technically seems to work, but....ugh. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: You don't need `repmat`, Octave implicitly expands the singleton dimensions for the arrays to match. All you need is the reshape of the `p` matrix: `sum(A.^reshape(p,[ones(1,ndims(A)),numel(p)]),ndims(A)+1)`. Of course, rahnema1's answer below is even nicer...

Comment: @CrisLuengo Your answer is cleaner than mine, I appreciate it! Thanks for the lesson on singleton dimensions, that's very useful to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `p` to be a row vector:

```
result = reshape(sum(A(:) .^ p, 2), size(A));
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much.